# NO installing ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

When I try to install ubuntu cd through this throws me this error

> this kernel requires an x86-64 cpu but only detected an i686 cpu

I wonder what happens and how to fix it

Comment: And if CPU is so old as to only run 32 bit, better to download Lubuntu or Xubuntu. Full Ubuntu will require too many system resources for that old of a system.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the 32bit version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Your CPU can just handle 32-Bit but you are trying to install the 64-Bit version of Ubuntu. You should download the 32Bit version or buy a new CPU. If you are having a 64Bit CPU but running it inside a virtual machine make sure you have victimisation enabled in the BIOS

Answer (score 0):

If you are using virtualization software, like VirtualBox or VMware Player, you'll need to change the OS version for the VM to its 64-bit equivalent. VMware Player is especially bad at this, because the 32-bit version just has the name of the OS, like "Ubuntu" and the 64-bit version actually says "Ubuntu 64-bit".

You should probably run the 64-bit version of the OS on a 64-bit CPU, even if you are running less than 4 GB of memory. There are [significant performance advantages](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ubuntu_x86_1304&num=4) to running a 64-bit OS on supported 64-bit processors.